# Fastest horizontal line <-> convex polygon intersection algorithm?

Tags: intersection, horizontal-line, convex-polygon

I need to solve a relatively simple thing -- I've got n-vertices convex 2D polygon and a horizontal (!) line with some 'y' coordinate. I need only one thing: to check if the polygon is crossed with this line (i.e. have 2 intersections) or not.

The fastest one I can think of is to find min/max y coordinates within a polygon (loop repeated n times with two compares and two stores) and then to compare if the min y <= y < max y.

Somehow I feel this could be solved more "mathematically" but I always end with slower code (for example vector way -- I need to compute differences for n[i] and n[i+1], then multiply them, add etc -- much slower then 2 cmps+stores).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. Unfortunately, caching/bounding boxes is possible in very limited way (the polygons are moving/rotating, a very few space in RAM etc) but I'll give it a look for sure.

Comment: I am in need of exactly the same thing. Just curious, what do you need it for? What is your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to check if your polygon has a point with y1 < y and one with y2 > y. As soon as you have found such two points, you're done. If you can index your points by the y-coordinate, that should be a fast lookup.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a horizontal 2d line then yes, the method you've described is probably the fastest. You could short circuit it as well, as if you get partway through the check and have a min + max that are > and < your y value then you have an intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it on the raw each time, then you're probably not going to find any trick to make it faster than that.

If you can cache the min/max Y value with the polygon, then you can save time by not looping each vertex every time you do the test.

If your polygon has an aligned bounding box associated with it, you can test it against the box extents instead of the polygon and get the same result faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, is described here:
[optimal algorithm if line intersects convex polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497841/optimal-algorithm-if-line-intersects-convex-polygon).
But because you are handling with orthogonal lines, you can simplify it a little bit :). Thus the total complexity is log N without storing values.

Comment: It would be useful if you added the code to your answer and referenced it with the link. That way, if the link stops working, then your answer will still be useful.