# Inside-Outside-Test of an Triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, math, raytracing

I try to write an method `bool intersect(const Ray& ray, Intersection& intersection)` that returns true, when the Intersection is inside the Triangle.

What i've done so far , is check if there are Points on the Plane, that is created by 2 Vectors of the Triangle.

The Problem is now to check, if the Point is inside the Triangle.I use barycentric Coordinates

```
Vec3 AB = b_-a_;
Vec3 AC = c_-a_;
double areaABC = vec_normal_triangle.dot(AB.cross(AC));

Vec3 PB = b_-intersection.pos;
Vec3 PC = c_-intersection.pos;
double alpha = vec_normal_triangle.dot(PB.cross(PC));

Vec3 PA = a_-position.pos;
double beta = vec_normal_triangle.dot(PC.cross(PA));
double gamma = 1-alpha-beta;

if((beta+gamma) < 1 && beta > 0 && gamma > 0) {
    return true;
}
```

Actually its not even a triangle, just about random Points.
Can someone explain me or knows how i compute the barycentric Coordinates for 3 given Vectors?

Comment: What do you want ? The barycenter ? What barycentric coordinates are ? Or how to test whether a ray intersects a convex polygon ? In the latter case, see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497841/optimal-algorithm-if-line-intersects-convex-polygon). Remember that a convex polygon with 3 vertices is always a triangle ! So you can just read the answers of that question with `n=3`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `vec_normal_triangle` is the vector computed as `AB.cross(AC)` normalized (in other words, the triangle's normal), you should divide `alpha` and `beta` by `areaABC` to get the barycentric coordinates of the intersecton point.

```
double alpha = vec_normal_triangle.dot(PB.cross(PC)) / areaABC;
```

and

```
double beta = vec_normal_triangle.dot(PC.cross(PA)) / areaABC;
```

This normalizes `alpha` and `beta` so that your computation of `gamma` and comparison against 1 make sense.

I'd also like to make a suggestion. To avoid recomputation and make the code a bit cleaner you could replace your test with the following.

```
if(alpha > 0 && beta > 0 && gamma > 0) {
    return true;
}
```

Aside from that, I see that you first use `intersection.pos` and then `position.pos`. Is this intentional? My guess is that you need to use `intersection.pos` both times.

Comment: yep you are right, this should be intersection.pos.

Comment: @lolio Did this answer solve your problem? If so, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.